# User not able to login for sync Outlook calendar events in iOS app - Swift

Tags: swift, azure, azure-active-directory

I have register app in Azure Active Directory for Authentication. User can signin with development but when i upload app to appstore at that time user can not signin. So please suggest me if any setting for App

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is based on an inappropriate calendar is selected while creating an event or data not syncing to the server appropriately

- Make sure the application is **configured** properly and check user account is **enabled** for signin it should not locked out
- Try to reset your password and re-login again
- Try to clear your browser’s cookies and retry to sign in again
- check whether **Conditional Access policy** and **Multi-Factor Authentication** is not block user access
- Make sure the correct licenses applied to your account.

To fix this issue,you can download and run the [Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant](https://aka.ms/SaRA-OfficeSignInScenario).

If issue remain same please Contact [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/contactus/)

For your reference :

[Problems signing in application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-sign-in-problem-first-party-microsoft)

[You can't sign in to the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/sign-in/sign-in-to-office-365-azure-intune#you-cant-sign-in-to-the-portal)